# Divisors of sequence $n,P(n),P(P(n)),\ldots$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial with nonnegative integer coefficients consisting of more than one nonzero term. Let $n$ be a positive integer. Is the set of prime numbers which divide at least one number in the sequence $n,P(n),P(P(n)),\ldots$ necessarily infinite?

When $P(x)$ consists of only one term, the set of prime divisors is always finite. (Say, $P(x)=5x^9$.) My guess is that when $P(x)$ consists of more than one term, the set of prime divisors is always infinite. But how can we relate the prime divisors between $k$ and $P(k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $P(0) \ne 0$. Let $e(m)$ be the smallest positive number such that $P^{e(m)}(0) \equiv 0$ mod $m$ (if it exists).  If $S$ is the finite set of primes we suppose are allowed to divide $P^k(n)$ with arbitrarily high exponent, we can choose $x$ large enough that for all $p \in S$, $e(p^x) \ge |S| + 1$.  Now in any contiguous subsequence of length $|S| + 1$ we can find at least one value that is not divisible by $p^x$ for any $p \in S$ (by the pigeonhole principle), but the largest possible such value is $\prod_{p \in S}p^{x-1}$, and the sequence is increasing without bound: contradiction.

Unfortunately I don't know what to do about the $P(0) = 0$ case.  We can first write $P(x) = x^a \cdot Q(x)$ where $Q(0) \ne 0$ but I can't figure out how to adapt the above argument.

Comment: Why would the $P^k(n)$ be contiguous? It's typically a very fast growing sequence...

Comment: @Lord_Farin, what I meant is that at least one of $P^k(n), P^{k+1}(n), \dots, P^{k+|S|}(n)$ has no prime factor in $S$ with exponent greater than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Ah, I get it now, thanks. Just had to read it once more :).